NoSuchDriverException Error when exporting Links using Selenium
I want to setup a script to export links from a website that is generated once you enter a URL. The website in question is pagespeed.web.dev. I have 0 knowledge, so while yes I know it's not the best option, I went with ChatGPT for help. It seemed to work pretty well all things considered with just 1 URL, but once I tried to do 5 it just crapped out. Note: from what I understand I am not data scraping, you just enter the URL in the box, click Analyze, and then copy the link with a button.
Here is the code itself:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pyperclip  # For clipboard operations

# Replace with the path to your GeckoDriver
geckodriver_path = r'C:\Users\*****.OSHS\Documents\geckodriver.exe'

# Replace with the URL of the website performance tool
website_url = 'https://pagespeed.web.dev/'

# Replace with the placeholder text for the input box and the export button
input_box_placeholder = 'Enter a web page URL'
analyze_button_xpath = '/html/body/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/button/span'  # Ensure this XPath correctly identifies the button
copy_button_xpath = '/html/body/header/span/div[1]/button/span'  # Adjust this XPath if needed

# Replace with your website URL
website_to_monitor = [
    'https://www.ohiostatewaterproofing.com',
    'https://www.basementwaterproofing.com',
    'https://www.everdrywaterproofinglouisville.com/',
    'https://www.stablwall.com',
    'https://www.everdrycolumbus.com'
]

# Initialize the WebDriver for Firefox
service = Service(executable_path=geckodriver_path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)

# File to save the results
results_file = 'website_performance_reports.txt'

def get_report_link(driver, website_url):
    try:
        # Open the website performance tool
        driver.get(website_url)
    
        # Initialize WebDriverWait
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    
        # Wait for the input box by placeholder text and then find it
        input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//input[@placeholder="{input_box_placeholder}"]')))
        input_box.send_keys(website_to_monitor)
    
        # Wait for the analyze button to be clickable and then find it
        analyze_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, analyze_button_xpath)))
        analyze_button.click()
    
        # Wait for the analysis to complete (adjust the sleep duration as needed)
        time.sleep(30)  # Adjust this as needed based on the website's performance
    
        # Simulate the click to copy the link
        copy_button_xpath = '/html/body/header/span/div[1]/button/span'  # Replace with the actual XPath for the copy button
        copy_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, copy_button_xpath)))
        copy_button.click()
    
        # Get the copied link from the clipboard
        report_link = pyperclip.paste()
        
        return report_link
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving report for {website_url}: {e}")
        return None

def save_results(results):
    with open(results_file, 'w') as file:
        for url, report_link in results:
            file.write(f"Website: {url}\n")
            file.write(f"Report Link: {report_link}\n")
            file.write("----\n")

def main():
    # Initialize the WebDriver for Firefox
    service = Service(executable_path=geckodriver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
    
    results = []
    
    for website in website_to_monitor:
        print(f"Processing {website}...")
        report_link = get_report_link(driver, website)
        results.append((website, report_link))
    
    # Save all results to a file
    save_results(results)
    
    driver.quit()
    print(f"All reports saved to {results_file}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Blocked out my username but that path works
I tried to work with ChatGPT and keep using its suggestions to fix things, but it seems that every fix doesn't help. This is the error I get from the terminal:
Error retrieving report for https://www.ohiostatewaterproofing.com: Message:
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:193:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:511:5
dom.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/shared/DOM.sys.mjs:136:16

Code error without try/except statements:
File "C:\Users\*****.OSHS\OSW-Test.py", line 31, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\*****.OSHS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 57, in __init__
    if finder.get_browser_path():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\*****.OSHS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 47, in get_browser_path
    return self._binary_paths()["browser_path"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\*****.OSHS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 78, in _binary_paths
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for firefox; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location


I edited your ai generated code a bit but I didn't rewrite it
first of all, you had an issue with Firefox so I changed it to Chrome
you had multiple bugs because of the auto-generated code in the function get_report_link  driver.get("") was using website_url which is the same as the function parameter this resulted in Selenium opening all of the website_to_monitor sites instead of https://pagespeed.web.dev
I removed that time.sleep(30) it was useless since you already have wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30) it does the same thing, waiting for element to appear with a timeout of 30 seconds and you had a repeated service and driver declarations at the top of your code and in the function get_report_link so i removed it too, your code was mostly working didn't need too many changes
I also cleaned the code a little bit from the useless AI comments
this is your code hope it works now
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pyperclip

# Replace with the path to your GeckoDriver
chrome_driver_path = 'add chrome driver path here'

# Replace with the placeholder text for the input box and the export button when needed
input_box_placeholder = 'Enter a web page URL'
analyze_button_xpath = '/html/body/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/button/span'
copy_button_xpath = '/html/body/header/span/div[1]/button/span'

# Replace with your website URL
website_to_monitor = [
    'https://www.ohiostatewaterproofing.com',
    'https://www.basementwaterproofing.com',
    'https://www.everdrywaterproofinglouisville.com/',
    'https://www.stablwall.com',
    'https://www.everdrycolumbus.com'
]

# File to save the results
results_file = 'website_performance_reports.txt'


def get_report_link(driver: Chrome, website_url: str):
    """ automating the generate report task """
    # Open the website performance tool
    driver.get('https://pagespeed.web.dev/')

    # Initialize WebDriverWait
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

    # Wait for the input box by placeholder text and then find it
    input_box = wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//input[@placeholder="{input_box_placeholder}"]')))
    input_box.send_keys(website_url)

    # Wait for the analyze button to be clickable and then find it
    analyze_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, analyze_button_xpath)))
    analyze_button.click()

    copy_button_xpath = '/html/body/header/span/div[1]/button/span'  # Replace with the actual XPath for the copy button
    copy_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, copy_button_xpath)))
    copy_button.click()

    # Get the copied link from the clipboard
    report_link = pyperclip.paste()

    return report_link


def save_results(results: list):
    """ saving all results to a file """
    with open(results_file, 'w') as file:
        for url, report_link in results:
            file.write(f"Website: {url}\n")
            file.write(f"Report Link: {report_link}\n")
            file.write("----\n")


def main():
    """ main function to start the script """
    service = ChromeService(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
    driver = Chrome(service=service)

    results = []

    for website in website_to_monitor:
        print(f"Processing {website}...")
        report_link = get_report_link(driver, website)
        results.append((website, report_link))

    save_results(results)
    driver.quit()
    print(f"All reports saved to {results_file}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

about the issue you had, I don't know why it happened maybe the file is not in the  same place, or maybe it's an issue with Firefox itself I also had an issue with Firefox running your code so I decided to replace Firefox with chrome
